# android setVisible on textView and editText is not taking effect immediately

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a simple layout which includes 2 textviews and 2 edittexts, along with a couple spinners. My issue is that, depending on the value of the first spinner, I want to show or hide certain views or change the text on certain labels. My implementation works fine except that whenever setVisible(View.INVISIBLE) is called, the edittext and textview will not actually dissappear until I click on something else on the screen. Once I click on, for example, the edit text which I am not hiding, the views that I want hidden will go ahead and dissappear. Ive tried calling invalidate() on them as I've seen in other posts to refresh a view but it is not working. I've posted the XML layout and relevant java code below. All help is appreciated.

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              tools:context="com.greg.android.youcast.FieldDisplayActivity"
              tools:showIn="@layout/activity_field_display">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/run_or_play_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passer_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/passer_name_label"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passer_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:hint="@string/passer_name_edit_text"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/receiver_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"

            android:text="@string/receiver_name_label"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/receiver_name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:hint="@string/receiver_name_edit_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yards_gained_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="@string/yards_gained"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/yards_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_play_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/submit_play_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and the pertinent java code:

```
...
runOrPlaySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String choice = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (choice.equals("Run")) {
                    setRunPlayUIFields();
                } else if (choice.equals("Pass")) {
                    setPassPlayUIFields();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

        });

....
private void setRunPlayUIFields() {
        passerNameLabel.setText("Runner Name: ");
        receiverNameField.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        receiverNameLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        receiverNameField.refreshDrawableState();
        passerNameField.setHint("Runner Name");
        this.receiverNameField.invalidate();
        this.receiverNameLabel.invalidate();
    }

    private void setPassPlayUIFields() {
        passerNameLabel.setText(R.string.passer_name_label);
        receiverNameLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        receiverNameField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        passerNameField.setHint("Passer Name");
        this.receiverNameField.invalidate();
        this.receiverNameLabel.invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML Layout, make it so that you set your

`android:id="@+id/receiver_name_text_view"`
has the property of
`android:visibility="visible"`

You can try that, or if you want you can try - in your Java code - to do the following:

`receiverNameField.setAlpha(0.0f);` to make it invisible

`receiverNameField.setAlpha(1.0f);` to make it visible

Comment: Adding the visible xml attribute did not work however using setAlpha did. Seems odd i would need to accomplish things this way instead of setVisible. Especially when setvisible(View.VISIBLE) works as expected. Anyways it works thanks

Comment: I personally use the alpha to make objects look like they're fading out if you are into that kind of stuff. Anyways I'm glad that it worked for you! Happy Programming!